# For loop failing in two instances on python exercise

Tags: python

I'm new to python and have been doing online exercises, and was wondering if someone could explain why the solutions below are failing. I have two solutions, each producing different failures as shown in the output. Thanks!!

Also, why do I need to assign a variable in my second block of code but not my first? If I don't assign a variable I get a `pop index out of range error`.

**PROBLEM**

Return the sum of the numbers in the array, returning 0 for an empty array. Except the number 13 is very unlucky, so it does not count and numbers that come immediately after a 13 also do not count.

```
sum13([1, 2, 2, 1]) → 6
sum13([1, 1]) → 2
sum13([1, 2, 2, 1, 13]) → 6
```

**SOLUTION 1**

```
def sum13(nums):
    for i in nums: 
      if i == 13 and (nums.index(i) > len(nums) - 2):
        nums.pop(nums.index(i))
        continue       
      if i == 13 and (nums.index(i) < len(nums) - 1):      
        y = nums.index(i)
        nums.pop(y)
        nums.pop(y) + 1              
return sum(nums)     




sum13([13, 1, 2, 13, 2, 1, 13]) → 3               3 OK       
sum13([]) → 0                                     0 OK       
sum13([13]) → 0                                   0 OK       
sum13([13, 13]) → 0                               0 OK       
sum13([13, 0, 13]) → 0                  FAILED    13 X       
sum13([13, 1, 13]) → 0                  FAILED    13 X      
sum13([5, 7, 2]) → 14                             14 OK       
sum13([5, 13, 2]) → 5                             5 OK       
sum13([0]) → 0                                    0 OK       
sum13([13, 0]) → 0                                0 OK       
other tests                                       OK
```

**SOLUTION 2**

```
def sum13(nums):
    for i in nums: 
      if i == 13 and (nums.index(i) > len(nums) - 2):
        nums.pop(nums.index(i))
        continue       
      if i == 13 and (nums.index(i) < len(nums) - 1):      
        y = nums.index(i)
        nums.pop(y)
        nums.pop(y) + 1     
      if i == 13 and len(nums) <= 1:
        return 0
    return sum(nums)


sum13([13, 1, 2, 13, 2, 1, 13]) → 3                3 OK       
sum13([]) → 0                                      0 OK       
sum13([13]) → 0                                    0 OK       
sum13([13, 13]) → 0                                0 OK       
sum13([13, 0, 13]) → 0                             0 OK       
sum13([13, 1, 13]) → 0                             0 OK       
sum13([5, 7, 2]) → 14                             14 OK       
sum13([5, 13, 2]) → 5                      FAILED  0 X       
sum13([0]) → 0                                     0 OK       
sum13([13, 0]) → 0                                 0 OK       
other tests                                FAILED    X
```

Comment: Don't remove items from a list while iterating over it.

Comment: Add `print nums` to the beginning of your loop body and it should clear up exactly what's happening.

Comment: +1 for showing us what you have tried and an input/output example.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you're trying to actually do nums.pop(y+1) in your second if, but besides that error, it won't work anyway, because you just popped a value out of the array, so your index values have changed.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with everybody else. You don't want to be modifying a list as you are iterating through it.

Here is a simple solution I wrote for your problem.

```
def sum13(nums):
    # start unlucky_index  at a big number so it can never practically happen
    # at the beginning
    unlucky_index = 0xFFFF 
    sum = 0

    for i, num in enumerate(nums):

        # if num is 13 save index of that 13
        if num == 13:
            unlucky_index = i
            continue
        # if this is the next number after the 13 index
        # then ignore
        if i == unlucky_index + 1:
            continue

        sum += num

    print "sum =",sum # debug only

    return sum
```

Answer (score 0):

Listen to the comments - dont remove objects from a list while iterating over it unless you know what you are doing.

I'v written another code that is a bit more [Pythonic](http://blog.startifact.com/posts/older/what-is-pythonic.html). Have a look at it, and see if you can use it in some way.

```
def sum13(nums):
    running_total = 0
    # Make an iterator of the provided numbers. This enables us to call
    # next on it, even inside the for loop.
    inums = iter(nums)
    for n in inums:

        # Drop this number, and drop next number in the sequence.
        if n == 13:
            try:
                next(inums)    
            # If StopIteration is raised, it means that the current item
            # was the last in the iterator - break out of the loop
            except StopIteration:
                break
            continue

        # If not 13, add the current number to the running total
        else:
            running_total += n
    return running_total
```